# displaying csv data in four columns in php

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have `complaint.csv` file in which data is like below:

```
1,complaint of health
2,complaint of money
.
.
.
71,complaint of bill
```

I want to show above data in four columns in PHP such that each column will have equal numbers of rows.

I have tried below **code** in which I couldn't able to get success.

```
           <?php 

  $fp = file('../complaint.csv', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$total_rows = count($fp);

  $count = $total_rows;
$first_col = ceil($count/ 4); 
$count -= $first_col;
$second_col = ceil($count/ 3);
$count -= $second_col ;
$third_col = ceil($count/ 2);
$forth_col = $count - $third_col ;

while (!feof($fp)) {

$lines[] = fgetcsv($fp, 1024);

}
fclose($fp);

                ?>
           <div class="added">
           <div class="column-left">
                <?php
                for ($i = 0; $i < $first_col; $i++)
                {
                    foreach ( $lines as $line):
                    ?>
                        <label class="checkbox" for="<?php print 'checkbox'.$line[$i][0]; ?>" style="font-size:20px;">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="<?php print $line[$i][0]; ?>" id="<?php print 'checkbox'.$line[$i][0]; ?>" data-toggle="checkbox">
                        <?php print $line[$i][1]; ?>
                        </label>
                    <?php
                    endforeach;
                }
                ?>
           </div>

           <div class="column-center">
            <?php
             $k = $i;
                for ($j = 0; $j < $second_col; $j++)
                {
                    foreach ( $lines as $line):
                    ?>
                        <label class="checkbox" for="<?php print 'checkbox'.$line[$j][0]; ?>" style="font-size:20px;">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="<?php print $line[$j][0]; ?>" id="<?php print 'checkbox'.$line[$j][0]; ?>" data-toggle="checkbox">
                        <?php print $line[$j][1]; ?>
                        </label>
                    <?php
                    endforeach;
                    $k++;
                }
                ?>
          </div>

            <div class="column-center-right">
            <?php
             $m = $k;
                for ($l = 0; $l < $third_col; $l++)
                {
                    foreach ( $lines as $line):
                    ?>
                        <label class="checkbox" for="<?php print 'checkbox'.$line[$l][0]; ?>" style="font-size:20px;">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="<?php print $line[$l][0]; ?>" id="<?php print 'checkbox'.$line[$l][0]; ?>" data-toggle="checkbox">
                        <?php print $line[$l][1]; ?>
                        </label>
                    <?php
                    endforeach;
                    $m++;
                }
                ?>
           </div>

            <div class="column-right">
            <?php
             $n = $k;
                for ($p = 0; $p < $forth_col; $p++)
                {
                    foreach ( $lines as $line):
                    ?>
                        <label class="checkbox" for="<?php print 'checkbox'.$line[$p][0]; ?>" style="font-size:20px;">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="<?php print $line[$p][0]; ?>" id="<?php print 'checkbox'.$line[$p][0]; ?>" data-toggle="checkbox">
                        <?php print $line[$p][1]; ?>
                        </label>
                    <?php
                    endforeach;
                    $n++;
                }
                ?>
           <br/>
          </div>

           </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    <style>
    .column-left{ float: left; width: 25%; }
    .column-right{ float: right; width:25%; }
    .column-center{ float: left; width: 25%; }
    .column-center-right{ float: left; width: 25%; }
div.added {
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: "freightbook";
    color: #2a4753;
    text-align: left;
}
    </style>
```

I am getting **Error** like `Notice: Uninitialized string offset`. The affected lines are between `foreach loop`

Can anyone please tell me, what went wrong in above code or any other solution of it?

Comment: Can you show sample output that you are expecting?

Comment: http://www.codedevelopr.com/articles/reading-csv-files-into-php-array/ use this

Comment: @Alankar More I have added Expected output above. In above case each column will have 18,18,18,17 lines from csv file

Comment: what is the line where you get the error?

Comment: @Lelio Faieta Error getting on line like this in foreach loop `<?php print $line[$i][1]; ?>`.

Comment: Man, if you are using "file" to access complain.csv, you should know you are working with an array. But you are treating that as a resource (feof, fgetcsv and fclose expect resources). So, use fopen to open your file or don't use all that instructions. You code is full of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

- Variable number of columns
- Unequal number of lines are filled from left to right
- Formatting of HTML elements thru styles (CSS)

### Input (complaint.csv)

```
1,complaint of health
2,complaint of money
3,complaint type 3
4,complaint type 4
5,complaint type 5
6,complaint type 6
7,complaint type 7
8,complaint type 8
9,complaint of bill
```

### Code

```
<?php

    // Setup ---------------------------------------------------------------        
    define('numcols',4);  // set the number of columns here
    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('./complaint.csv'));
    $numcsv = count($csv);
    $linespercol = floor($numcsv / numcols);
    $remainder   = ($numcsv % numcols);
    // Setup ---------------------------------------------------------------        

    // Page, part 1 --------------------------------------------------------
    echo '<html
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        BODY { font-family:tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:76%; }
        .table { background-color: #e0e0e0; }
        .break { break:both; border:0; with:1px; }
        .column {  border:0; float:left; padding:0.333em; }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    ';    
    // Page, part 1 --------------------------------------------------------

    // The n-column table --------------------------------------------------
    echo '<div class="table">'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '   <div class="column">'.PHP_EOL;

    $lines = 0;
    $lpc   = $linespercol;
    if ($remainder>0) { $lpc++; $remainder--; }
    foreach($csv as $item) {
        $lines++;
        if ($lines>$lpc) {
            echo '   </div>' . PHP_EOL . '<div class="column">'.PHP_EOL;
            $lines = 1;
            $lpc   = $linespercol;
            if ($remainder>0) { $lpc++; $remainder--; }
        }
        echo '      <label class="checkbox" for="checkbox'.$item[0].'" style="font-size:20px;">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="'.$item[0].'" id="'.$item[0].'" data-toggle="checkbox">'
                        .$item[1].
                    '</label><br />';
    }
    echo '   </div>'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '</div>'.PHP_EOL;
    // The n-column table --------------------------------------------------

    // Page, part 2 --------------------------------------------------------             
    echo '</body>
    </html>
    ';
    // Page, part 2 --------------------------------------------------------        

?>
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: is there any way to code it without changing original css?

Comment: Yes, of course. At least you should leave **.column {  float:left; }** intact, as it governs the alignment (floating left) of the DIVs that surround the columns. You also could replace **<div class="column"...** by **<div style="float:left;..."** and forget about the style definitions at the top. Or use your style definitions (one for all columns: _float:left_, since my solution is not tied to 4 columns).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. By using the PHP inbuilt SPL classes.

```
 <?php
            $file = new SplFileObject("./FL_insurance_sample.csv", "r");
            $file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
            $file->seek($file->getSize());
            $linesTotal = $file->key();
            $recordsInColumn = floor($linesTotal / 4);
            $res = array();
            foreach ($file as $line) :
                $res[] = $line;
            endforeach;
            $finalRecord = array_chunk($res, $recordsInColumn);
            $classNames = array('column-left','column-right','column-center','column-center-right');
            foreach ($finalRecord as $key => $data) : ?>
            <div class="<?php echo $classNames[$key]; ?>"> 
                <?php foreach ($data as $key1 => $row) :
                    if ($row[0] !== null && $row[1] !== null):
                        ?>
                        <label class="checkbox" for="<?php print 'checkbox' . $row[0]; ?>" style="font-size:20px;">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="complaint" value="<?php print $row[0]; ?>" id="<?php print 'checkbox' . $row[0]; ?>" data-toggle="checkbox">
                            <?php print $row[1]; ?>
                        </label>
                        <?php
                    endif;
                endforeach; ?>
             </div>   
            <?php endforeach;
    ?>
```